# How can I tell if a modem will work with FTTC?

Tags: modem

I'm looking to split our networks within our house, where we have 2 x freelance businesses with NAS, as well as home needs (my post https://serverfault.com/questions/749387/improving-soho-network-security)is the precursor to this). As my ISP router is not suitable for this setup, I will need a FTTC-compatible modem or modem/router.

For the new modem, what terms/identifiers are there to indicate whether one will work with FTTC/"superfast BB"?  Or if they all work, to make use of the extra speed.

I have read around but am still unsure - is it VDSL/VDSL2 or ADSL2+ or something else I should be looking for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only actual solution to this is "Ask your ISP", because we don't know. I just looked up `FTTC` and that's where the fiber does not terminate on your premesis, so there still needs to be some method of last-mile delivery. Only your ISP can tell you what that method is going to be.

In most `FTTx` networks that terminate on your premises (`FTTP`, `FTTB`), you do not connect directly to your ISPs fiber. The fiber goes into an [ONT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_device#ONT). From there, it will break out into analogue phone ports, perhaps a coaxial service for connecting to a TV or set-top box, and finally an Ethernet port that delivers the internet connection. The ONT usually has support for a backup battery (not always fitted however), so that your analogue phones still work in the event of a power outage.

The part you need to concern yourself with is the ethernet that comes out of the ONT. Your ISP typically will provide you with a router that will suffice, but that router is more often than not, pretty stuff and shouldn't be used (the exception to this, that I've found, is the one that Verizon ship with FIOS is not too bad. But the one that Telstra ships with their NBN is pure garbage).

So what you actually need, is a standard router. If a router as VDSL/VDSL2/ADSL/DOCSIS then it's just *just* a router, it is a modem/router. You do not need a modem/router, you just need a router.

These are normally identifiable because they will not have any analogue port on the back of them. They will have the standard 4-or-so LAN ports all grouped together, and then another port, usually by itself, or colour coded differently, that is labelled "WAN".<sup>1</sup>

Feel free to also get a combination router/access point if you want to have WiFi on the same physical device as your router.

The advantage of doing this, even if it is not technically what your ISP is going to deliver your internet over, is you have a proper router that you can put a modem in front of if you need to. So if you get a nice Ethernet-based router, and then it turns out you need VDSL2+, then you can throw a [VDSL2+ converter](http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product.php?id=21837) between the copper and the ethernet port and call it a day.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is not always true. More serious devices like a Mikrotik Routerboard or a Cisco device will just have a bunch of ethernet ports and they leave it up to you to configure which ports connect to which networks, but it's probably not a good idea to recommend one of these to a regular consumer.</sup>

Comment: Before we got fibre BB I bought an ADSL2 modem to replace the ISP modem-router but wasn't sure if compatible with superfast BB. This has all helped clarify stuff: I have just found that ADSL2+ "has a max download speed of 24 Mb/s" so that would be a constraint as we get over 30Mb/s. The last paragraph clarifies what I need: VDSL/VDSL2 in some piece of hardware - not sure what the Ethernet/VDSL2 converter does differently to a modem. Before I invest in kit, will the ADSL2 modem work (sub-optimally) on my fibre connection? I would like to test out the configuration with the other routers I have?

Comment: If you really do have FTTC then forget about the fiber. It's just marketing. You will not have fiber to your house. You will have VDSL2+ which will be delivered over the phone line. This is not compatible with ADSL. The converter _is_ a modem, having it separate gives you more flexibility over your configuration. Reason being there are not many VDSL products on the market and you might not like the ones you can get.